# Recursive block expansion error when recursively yielding

Tags: recursion, crystal-lang

I was looking to implement Python's os.walk method in Crystal. I was trying to do it recursively, but the compiler was told me to be careful about recursive yielding because it recursively/infinitely would generate code when compiled. This is what I had

```
def walk(d = @root, &block)
  d = Dir.new(d) if d.is_a?(String)
  dirs, files = d.entries.partition { |s| Dir.exists?(File.join(d.path, s)) }
  if Dir.exists?(d.path)
    yield d.path, dirs, files
    dirs.each do |dir_name|
      # recursively yield
      walk File.join(d.path, dir_name), do |a, b, c|
        yield a, b, c
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

A few helpful members of the community on Gitter pointed me in the right direction and just wanted to share my learnings here. The answer is, is that you cannot use `yield` recursively but you must use the `block` variable instead (explanation to come). Here's what I ended up with:

```
def walk(d = @root, &block : String, Array(String), Array(String) -> )
  d = Dir.new(d) if d.is_a?(String)
  dirs, files = d.children.partition { |s| Dir.exists?(File.join(d.path, s)) }
  block.call(d.path, dirs, files)
  dirs.each do |dir_name|
    walk File.join(d.path, dir_name), &block
  end
end
```

The trick here is that instead of using the `yield` keyword you have to use `block.call` instead and forward your block. This is actually [already](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/block_forwarding.html) in the docs, but it's a little subtle. During compilation, if you have a `yield`, the compiler will literally inline your block where the yield is (as far as I understand). When using `block.call`, a function is created instead, and that's the reason we need to type the block argument. If you don't give it a type, `block.call` will expect 0 arguments. To pass things through, just type it similar to how I did it in this method signature.

Based on the above explanation, it makes sense why you wouldn't need to add a type to `block` when you just yield and it would just work. It's also important to understand why there's a performance difference between `yield` and `block.call`, since in one case a closing function is created versus the compiler inlining your code.

Comment: With `Dir#each_child` instead of `Dir#entries` you don't need to filter out `.` and `..`. Also it's not logical to call `Dir.exists?` after you already have created an iterator for the entries in that path.

Comment: Took another look and ```Dir#children``` was a drop in replacement for ```Dir#entries``` - thanks! As for the ```Dir#exists```, i'm not checking for existence but rather is the path a directory. If there's a better way of doing that, let me know, but looking at the code for ```Dir#exists``` it doesn't look like it's doing much other than a wrapper around File.stat and checking if it's a directory. Dunno how I can check if a path is a directory in a cheaper way

Comment: You don't need to check if `d.path` exists. If it wouldn't, `Dir.new` had already raised.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now (was looking at the wrong line). Good point, thanks. Just updated